# Is there any alternative ways to check the value of particular index is empty or not in python list

Tags: python, list

```
def fn():
    return {'Name': 'John'}, False #, {'extra': 'welcome', 'to': 'dev@dsds.com'}

results, *returns = fn()

is_multiple = returns[0] if len(returns) > 0 else False
extra_params = returns[1] if len(returns) > 1 else None

print(is_multiple)
print(extra_params)
```

Any other alternative ways to check whether the `extra_params` is empty or not?

Except the above `len` solution or without using the `try` catch `IndexError` exception handler..

Comment: Your code does make much sense but you can also always just do `if returns`.

Comment: A plain `if returns` should also work: it evaluates to `False` for an empty list.

Comment: Simple `extra_params = returns[1] **if returns** else None`, gives an IndexError `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: why do you need this alternative? is this about to check the validity of the index or if the value at the index is None (or a specific "missing value" identifier)?

Comment: Thats because `returns` isn't a list. You have an error in your code with `returns, *returns`... You use the same variable twice. You should really consider not using this code...

Comment: @MrFuppes 1. using `len`, takes some extra time to execute, Instead expecting some built-in mechanism to handle this by the Python itself. 2. Using `try`, I don't like the multiple line of code for checking this kind of simple condition. Looks like the code, becomes a little messy.

Comment: can you explain what it is exactly you want to achieve? I think there may be another way of achieving what you need.

Comment: @JaiK ok I see your point; conditional statements can become nasty. More general, in native Python I try to avoid working with indices at all whenever possible.

Comment: @JoshSharkey Sometimes, the third param will not be return from `fn()`.. At this time how to handle this at calling side? Without using the above solution or try mechanism. (Expecting the way like for checking the key exists or not in dict using `my_dict.get('some_key')`)

Comment: If you initialize the variables as `None` then you can make sure that the same number of values always returns. Now whenever you call `fn()` you will recieve the same amount of return values. You can check to makes sure the return value `is not None` after you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to define your value returned by your function as a three value tuple and use `None` or an empty `dict` if you don't have a value eg:

```py
def fn():
    return {'Name': 'John'}, False, None

results, is_multiple, extra_params = fn()
```

This is much simpler and avoids the need for checking lengths.

If you are writing backwards-compatible code, for example, an alternative is to not do the tuple unpacking up front eg:

```py
def fn():
    return {'Name': 'John'}, False, # {}

response = fn()

# At least two items must be returned else length might not be valid.
if len(response) == 2:
    results, is_multiple = response
    extra_params = None
elif len(response) == 3:
    results, is_multiple, extra_params = response
else:
    raise ValueError("Unexpected response...")
```

Although I would recommend the first much simpler design, there are lots of ways to mess up the second design and cause unexpected errors.